# Access global static value inside thread in powershell

Tags: multithreading, powershell

In Powershell I have a class with a static value

```
class SharedData {
    static [int]$Counter = 0
}
```

When I try to access the value inside a thread like this

```
if([SharedData]::Counter -eq 0) {
    $resultsQueue.Enqueue("Test only")
}
```

It throws an `The type [SharedData] was not found.` exception. How to make the static value accessible in a multythreaded powershell script?

Here is my whole repro:

```
 Set-StrictMode -Version latest

class SharedData {
    static [int]$Counter = 0
}

$lockObject = [System.Object]::new()
[int]$global:counter = 0

# Set up a queue to store results
$resultsQueue = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue[string]]::new()

# Create an array to hold the runspaces
$runspaces = @()

# Create and start 10 threads (runspaces)
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
    $runspace = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
        param($lockObject, $resultsQueue)

        function GetNextJob_Lock {
            param($lockObject, $resultsQueue)

            # Enter the critical section (lock)
            [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($lockObject)
            try {
                if([SharedData]::Counter -eq 0) {
                    $resultsQueue.Enqueue("Test only")
                    }
            }
            catch {
                $resultsQueue.Enqueue($_.Exception.Message)
            }
            finally {
                # Exit the critical section (unlock) in a finally block
                [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit($lockObject)
            }
        }

        # Execute the job and enqueue the result
        $result = GetNextJob_Lock -lockObject $lockObject -resultsQueue $resultsQueue

    }).AddArgument($lockObject).AddArgument($resultsQueue)
    $runspaces += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Pipe = $runspace
        Handle = $runspace.BeginInvoke()
    }
}

# Wait for all threads to finish
$runspaces | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Pipe.EndInvoke($_.Handle)
    $_.Pipe.Dispose()
}

# Declare $result before using it in TryDequeue with [ref]
$result = $null

# Display results from the queue
while ($resultsQueue.TryDequeue([ref]$result)) {
    Write-Output $result
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) definitions aren't available across runspaces. This includes not just runspaces created explicitly via the PowerShell SDK, but also those created implicitly by [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) and the v7+ [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object#notes) feature.

You have 2-3 basic options, depending on what PowerShell version you use; the first two options work in both *Windows PowerShell* and [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the third one requires v7.4+ of the latter:

- Instead of using a PowerShell class, use a dictionary instance, such as of type [`` System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary-2) (note that while this type is generally thread-safe, you'll still need to explicitly synchronize updates to a *given entry's* value).
- Compile your class *via C# source code* and [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type). The resulting .NET type (which won't have direct access to the PowerShell engine) is invariably visible session-wide, i.e. in all runspaces of the same process.
- In PowerShell (Core) *v7.4+* only: decorate your `PowerShell` class with the [`[NoRunspaceAffinity()]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes?view=powershell-7.4#norunspaceaffinity-attribute) (for safe access from multiple runspaces) and pass your class *via a variable* to the other runspaces. As shown in the following simplified example (synchronization code omitted):

  ```bash
  # v7.4+ only
  [NoRunspaceAffinity()] class SharedData { static [int] $Counter = 42 }

  # Store the class' type in a variable.
  $sharedDataType = [SharedData]

  # In another runspace, reference the class via the variable.
  # Synchronization code omitted.
  'foo' | 
    ForEach-Object -Parallel {
       ($using:sharedDataType)::Counter
    }
  ```

Comment: @marsh-wiggle ConcurrentDictionary type is available in Windows PowerShell too